# Pause threads from a different thread, and then wait until all are paused

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to pause a number of worker thread from a creator thread. This can be done with a conditional variable, as seen in this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

#define NR_ITERATIONS 3
#define NR_THREADS 5

class c_threads {
private:
    bool m_worker_threads_pause;

    //std::atomic<int> m_worker_threads_paused;
    std::mutex m_worker_thread_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_worker_thread_conditional_variable;


    void worker_thread() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> worker_thread_lock(m_worker_thread_mutex);
        m_worker_thread_conditional_variable.wait(worker_thread_lock,
            [this]{return !this->m_worker_threads_pause;}
        );

        std::cout << "worker thread function" << std::endl;

        //...
    }

    void creator_thread() {
        std::cout << "creator thread function" << std::endl;

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_guard(m_worker_thread_mutex);
            m_worker_threads_pause = true;
        }
//        wait_until( worker_threads_waiting == NR_THREADS);


        //...


        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_guard(m_worker_thread_mutex);
            m_worker_threads_pause = false;
        }
        m_worker_thread_conditional_variable.notify_all();
    }

public:
    c_threads() :   m_worker_threads_pause(true)
                    /*m_worker_threads_paused(0)*/ {}

    void start_job() {
        std::vector<std::thread> worker_threads;
        worker_threads.reserve(NR_THREADS);

        for (int i=0;i<NR_THREADS;i++) {
            worker_threads.emplace_back(&c_threads::worker_thread,this);
        }

        std::thread o_creator_thread(&c_threads::creator_thread,this);
        o_creator_thread.join();

        for (auto& thread : worker_threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    c_threads o_threads;
    o_threads.start_job();
}
```

The problem is that the creator_thread function should wait until all worker_functions are waiting at the conditional variable before it proceeds.

Every time that the creator_thread function is called it should

1. Pause the worker threads
2. Wait until they are all paused at the condition variable
3. Proceed

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way, but I think you're going to have to do something a little more complicated, like create a gatekeeper object. Worker threads generally work like this:

```
while(iShouldKeepRunning()) {
    ... lock the mutex
    ... look for something to do
    ... if nothing to do, then wait on the condition
}
```

I think instead you would want some sort of "give me more work" object, or maybe a "is it safe to keep working" object that your creater thread can block.

```
while(iShouldKeepRunning()) {
    ... no mutex at all
    ... ask the gatekeeper for something to do / if it's safe to do something
    ... and the gatekeeper blocks as necessary
    ... do the work
}
```

The gatekeeper locks the mutex, checks if it's safe to give out work, and if it isn't, increments a "I'm making this guy wait" counter before blocking on the condvar.

Something like that.

The blocker might look something like:

```
class BlockMyThreads {
public:
     int runningCount = 0;
     int blockedCount = 0;
     bool mayWork = true;
     std::mutex myMutex;
     std::condition_variable condVar;

     void iAmWorking() {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
         ++runningCount;
     }

     void letMeWork() {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
         while (!mayWork) {
             ++blockedCount;
             condVar.wait(lock);
             --blockedCount;
         }
     }

     void block() {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
         mayWork = false;
     }

     void release() {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
         mayWork = true;
         condVar.notifyAll(lock);
     }
};
```

I haven't tested this, so there might be errors. Your worker threads would need to call iAmWorking() at the start (to give you a thread count) and you'd want to increment a decrement they call when they're done, I suppose.

The main thread can call block() and release() as you desire.

Comment: How would the creator thread know when "I'm making this guy wait" == NR_THREADS? Just do while(I'm making this guy wait!=NR_THREADS) {}?